# Cannot Resolve Symbol 'ApiClient' - Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm new to Retrofit and I'm trying to get data from my database and display it on my app's textviews. However, I'm getting one error message.

[image]

Comment: Where did you copy that line from? You need to implement that class yourself

Comment: I have the ApiService.class already.

Comment: import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;


public interface ApiService {
    @GET("localhost:8012/lara/getProfile.php?=")
    Call<Profile> getMyProfile(@Query("id") String id);
}

Comment: You just pasted API **Service**... You must implement a **class** named **ApiClient**

Comment: I'm following this tutorial: http://www.androidbie.com/2016/12/example-tutorial-retrofit-20-method-get.html

Comment: You must've skipped over the text that says *Third, create new java class, give it name as **ApiClient.java**, in this class we define the URL, set the LoggingInterceptor and client*... That block of code is missing, though, so find a different tutorial

Comment: that tutorial doesn't define ApiClient class u need to define it

Comment: Also, by the way, unless  your Android device is actually running your web server, `localhost` will never work

Comment: Hi, Before implement retrofit api calling please learn. what they do and how they do, Because you just copied the code,

Answer (score 2):

add this class in your project

```
public class ApiClient {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://example.com";
    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(getHTTPClient().build())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }


    private static OkHttpClient.Builder getHTTPClient() {
        final OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        return builder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @bhardwaj, however I'm getting two errors on private static OkHttpClient.Builder getHTTPClient() namely: Cannot Resolve Symbol 'NetworkStatusInterceptor' and Cannot resolve method 'getLoggingInterceptor'

Comment: @Vincent edited my answer it was a custom interceptor you can skip it

Answer (score 0):

You will need a class called `ApiClient` which is missing in the tutorial you are following

create a singleton instance of ApiClient and define your base URL

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

If you are new to retrofit I recommended you to refer this [link](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/)

Answer (score 0):

used below code for make retrofit object..

```
public class ApiClient {
private final static String LOCAL_URL = "http://192.168.101.170:9057/";
private final static String BASE_URL = LOCAL_URL;
// private final static String BASE_URL = " http://ftd.php1.projectbeta.biz/";
//private final static String BASE_URL_SECURE = "PASTE_YOUR_BASE_HTTPS_URL_HERE_";

public static ApiClient apiClient;
private Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static ApiClient getInstance() {
    if (apiClient == null) {
        apiClient = new ApiClient();
    }
    return apiClient;
}

//private static Retrofit storeRetrofit = null;

public Retrofit getClient() {
    return getClient(null);
}

private Retrofit getClient(final Context context) {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    client.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            if (context == null) {
                request = request
                        .newBuilder()
                        .build();
            } else {
                request = request
                        .newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + AppSetting.getStringSharedPref(context, Constants.USER_KEY_TOKEN, ""))
                        .build();
            }
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    return retrofit;
}
```

}